# HTML form values adding commas in Classic ASP

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP page that submits back to itself. Strangely, the values being returned from the selects have commas being added to the ends of them. Has anyone run into anything like this before? Any troubleshooting steps or tools recommended?

I'm expecting the values to be returned just as numbers - they are the IDs of the values displayed in the option.

I've checked for mystery commas in the page and can't locate any - nor in the data that I'm pulling through.

(note - these are single-selects, not multiple)

Comment: Some example code might shake out the problem...

Comment: Found the answer yet, or care to fill in some more details?

Comment: Apologies, I haven't had a chance to revist this project yet! I didn't realise that they would return comma-delimited if there were duplicate form values, so I'll definitely look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like you have duplicate form fields. Your values are concatenated together with commas, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="value1">
<input type="text" name="name1" value="value2">
<input type="text" name="name2" value="value3">
```

Becomes

```
name1=value1,value2
name2=value3
```

If the second `name1` has no value, it becomes

```
name1=value1,
name2=value3
```

Comment: This is actually something very simple that can lead to very complex results... I've just came around a really long route of debugging to find out that the fault was on on asp.net monolithic form and the use of multiple inputs with the same name thanks

Comment: Anyone know how to intercept a comma in the value of one of the form fields? I need the comma separated list of form values, but there is potential for one or more of those values to have a comma within it. Don't ask why, that's out of my control.

Comment: meh...I'll just replace the commas in the values before they render to the form and then put them back on post

Answer (score 3):

Do you have multiple form elements on your page with the same name?

In classic ASP, multiple form values with the same name are joined into a comma-separated string in the Request.Form / Request.QueryString collections - so if there's a hidden field or textbox with name="foo" as well as your <select name="foo">, you'll get the second (empty) value joined to the first, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Are there two form elements with the same name? If you have Firebug installed, it's worth taking a look to see if the data is actually being posted with the commas or if it's happening after ASP gets its awful paws on it.

Comment: At least it *has* paws. Not awful ragged claws like the monstrosity that is ASP.NET WebForms...

Comment: So you see WebForms as the J. Alfred Prufrock of programming?

Comment: Apparently so, although I didn't know that I did until I Googled J. Alfred Prufrock... ;)

Comment: as much as i hate webforms , i'm not in love with asp

Comment: That's good because it would qualify as necrophilia at this point.