# Array from Request.Form in classic asp

Tags: arrays, forms, vbscript, asp-classic

**EDIT: I now realise after the help from those who replied that my question was about whether Request.Form Data is a string in the same way that `a$="FooBar"` is a string and the `Array` command in Classic ASP.**

I'm trying to make an Array from data submitted in a Form.

The form fields are dynamically created and have the same name "subj".

The `Response.Write(Request.Form("subj"))` produces:

```
"Welcome and Introduction, Talk1, Talk2 ,Interactive review of the conference"
```

When I check the `TypeName` or `VarType` Request.Form("subj") is a string. Then I code:

```
subjs = """" & Replace(Request.Form("subj"), ", ", """,""") & """"
subjects = Array(subjs)
```

With the intention to give:

```
subjs = "Welcome and Introduction","Talk1","Talk2","Interactive review of the conference"

subjects(0) = Welcome and Introduction

subject(1) = Talk1

subject(2) = Talk2

subject(3) = Interactive review of the conference
```

The problem is that what I actually get is:

```vb
subjs = "Welcome and Introduction","Talk1","Talk2","Interactive review of the conference"

subject(0) = "Welcome and Introduction","Talk1","Talk2","Interactive review of the conference"
```

For some reason the Array isn't correctly formed as there is no subject(1) subject(2) or subject(3).

If I physically copy and paste the output of `subjs` into my code, then Array works fine but I can't get the Array to work on Form Data.

I've tried using `CStr` and checked all of the quotation marks.

Why doesn't it work?

**Thank you to those who took the trouble to reply. Whilst `Split` does work in fields without commas, `SET var = Request.Form("subj")` as per @Kul-Tigin, I think is the key but would be keen to hear other thoughts**

Comment: Split seems to work - [String to Array with Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954415/string-to-array-with-classic-asp?rq=1) `code subject = Split(Request.Form("subj"), ",")`

Comment: That's because Tony, that is the whole purpose of the `Split()` function. It takes a delimited string and splits it down into array elements based on a common delimiter you can specify, unlike `Array()` which creates an array from a list of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the request collection values may contain commas, using a split can cause unexpected results.

Creating an array through the collection is more reliable.

```vb
Set subject = Request.Form("subj")

ReDim subjects(subject.Count - 1)

For i = 1 To subject.Count
    subjects(i - 1) = subject(i)
Next
```

Comment: True but if your intention is to send a delimited list with the purpose of creating an array then you surely thought about that before hand and `Split()` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Lankymart what intention? I was answering `I'm trying to make an Array from data submitted in a Form.` in addition to @Martha's.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo meant to say *"True but if **the** intention"*. It wasn't aimed at you I was referring to the OP's intention was to send an array so `Split()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Either way it's a [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27954415/692942) and this answer was be better placed there not here.

Comment: I disagree that this is a dup. I know how to convert a string into an array, the problem came when the data was from a posted form. Thanks to @Kul-Tigin - I had tried `ReDim` unsuccessfully but had not used the `subject.Count-1` limit. I will try and post back assuming @Lankymart hasn't downgraded me so much that i get barred!

Comment: @Lankymart I see. OP's intention is clear as exampled in the question. He wants an array of Request.Form("subj") values. So it's definitely not a duplicate of `String to Array` question. No split mentioned in the question, it's just OP's incorrect solution. Here I'm trying to show the right path.

Comment: What a load of rubbish, multiple values with the same name in a form return to Classic ASP as a comma delimited string it doesn't take a genius to workout what comes next.

Comment: It's quite clear from the question that the OP realises they are receiving a delimited string from `Request.Form` they just don't know how to take that string and put it in an `Array` which is what that question covers. If the OP hadn't understood why they were getting a delimited string from `Request.Form` I would have [pointed them to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1863077/692942) and it would still have been a duplicate.

Comment: Dup or not, @Kul-Tigin solution works better for fields that contain commas in them. Thanks to all for their trouble

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` function expects a comma-separated list: `"words","stuff","foo"`, but what you get from a `Request.Form` is more like `"words,stuff,foo"`.

Ultimately, though, it doesn't matter, because as you've noted in your comment, the appropriate function to use is `Split`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming `split` is the correct way to deal with it. I thought that I had converted the text adequately by `Replace(Request.Form("subj"), ", ", """,""")` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: The OP already confirmed a few hours before you even answered that the question is a duplicate, just flag it and move on. Anyone who thinks a question about "Splitting into an Array" isn't a duplicate by now needs to re-read [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Thank you Martha. I've had a few problems with commas in the field text and moved to @Kul-Tigin's suggestion

Comment: @Tony_Wh: that's fine. `Split` should really only be used with fields where you define the values, i.e. checkboxes and radio buttons.