# Type mismatch: 'UBound'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Why do I get this error;

> Type mismatch: 'UBound'

```
Function JumbleArray(ByVal aArray)
    Dim iUpper, iLower, iLoop, iSwapPos, varTmp
    iUpper = UBound(aArray)
    iLower = LBound(aArray)

    Randomize Timer
    For iLoop = iLower To iUpper
        iSwapPos = Int(Rnd * (iUpper + 1))

        varTmp = aArray(iLoop)
        aArray(iLoop) = aArray(iSwapPos)
        aArray(iSwapPos) = varTmp
    Next

    JumbleArray = aArray
End Function

Dim strTestArray
strTestArray = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"

Shuffle = JumbleArray(strTestArray)
```

This code was proposed elsewhere but without any reports of it not working. It looks like it should work, but it does not.

The code shown here is everything that you need. By simply running the code you will see the error.

Comment: The functions expects an array. You are passing a string.

Comment: The array is assembled from selecting checkboxes, so how how can it be anything else?

Comment: @WilliamK show us the actual code instead of what you think the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array from Request.Form in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40706727/692942).

Comment: That is the actual code. But if you are referring to result from the form submission to create the array, then the array is exactly as defined here. Try the code above and you will get the same error.

Comment: @WilliamK you get the same error but not necessarily for the same reason. Have already showed you how to avoid that error with `Split()` and `IsArray()` for the string in your example, but from what you've said that isn't what you're actually passing.

Comment: I see that you flagged the other post as a possible duplicate also. Well Split doesn't solve this case. The question is simple and concise... a solution please?

Comment: strTestArray = "100002, 100003, 100001, 100000"

Comment: It doesn't come any other way and SPLIT doesn't do anything and IsArray fails!

Comment: @WilliamK you cannot return an Array to `Response.Write()` without first converting it to a string either by calling `Join()` or iterating over the elements in the array using a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, but from what I can see there are two main issues.

1. The function `UBound()` expects a valid array to return the upper bound, anything else will cause a `Type mismatch` error to be raised.

   The problem here is the function expects an `Array` but it is being passed a `String` *(as mentioned in the comments)*. If the string contains a valid string array *(a string that can be interpreted via delimiters to be a single dimension array)* you can use the `Split()` function to translate the string into a valid array and `IsArray()` to check a valid array is returned.
2. The function `JumbleArray()` returns an `Array` which cannot just be output to the page using `Response.Write()`. To output it you first need to check its a valid array using `IsArray()` then either use `Join()` to output the values or iterate over each element in the array using a loop.

When calling the function try this;

```
strTestArray = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
Dim TestArray: TestArray = Split(strTestArray, ",")
If IsArray(TestArray) Then
  TestArray = JumbleArray(TestArray)
  If IsArray(TestArray) Then
    Call Response.Write(Join(TestArray, ","))
  End If
Else
  Call Response.Write("Not a valid array")
End If
```